# How to get multiple input with char and multiple output with int? C++

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to C++, so I apologize if I am not sounding technical. I am having a little trouble getting a multiple input and output with my code, I'm thinking I should have a loop to get the data but i'm not sure how i'd go about that in my code, I've thought about using getline() but that doesn't seem to want to work with Char.

I've tried getline but I'm not sure how to implement it with the Char input, I believe I may need a separate loop as well but again not too sure. I'm thinking it could be done to EoF as well.

Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
char inpval; 
int outval = 0; 
cout << "Enter a Roman Number to convert: " << endl;
while (cin.get(inpval)) 
{
    inpval = toupper(inpval); 
    if (inpval == 'M')
        outval = outval + 1000;

    else if (inpval == 'D') {
        inpval = cin.peek(); 
        inpval = toupper(inpval);

        if (inpval == 'M') {
            outval = outval - 500;
            continue;
        } else {
            outval = outval + 500;
            continue;
        }
    }
  //etc     

cout << "The Equivalent Arabic value is:" << endl;
cout << outval << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

My expected output is:

(All on newline)
Input: 
I 
II
IV
V
VI

Output:
1
2
4
5
6

Actual output is:

Input:
I

Output:
1

P.S: The program converts Roman Numeral chars to their respected number.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can take input multiple items from cin, using below syntax.

```
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
cin >> c;
```

Another way is also there

```
cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

This technique is called "operator chaining" which is similar to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Use `getchar()`, Calculate/Convert Roman to integer until you encounter a space ' ',when you get a space `' '` output the integer and do the same next roman number until you get another space `' '` or newline `'\n'` and stop the program once you encounter newline `'\n'`.

Method 2:Use type `std::string` and take input with `getline`. Then iterate through the string and calculate until you find space `' '` output the number, do the same till you find next space `' '` or end when string ends.

If you know # of Roman numbers you want to convert you can put it in a loop.
Hope this helps.

Example(Method 2)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>



int value(char r) 
{ 
    if (r == 'I') 
        return 1; 
    if (r == 'V') 
        return 5; 
    if (r == 'X') 
        return 10; 
    if (r == 'L') 
        return 50; 
    if (r == 'C') 
        return 100; 
    if (r == 'D') 
        return 500; 
    if (r == 'M') 
        return 1000; 

    return -1; 
}




int main()
{
    int out=0;
    std::string s;
    std::string::iterator i; //string iterator
    //for more info go to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdstring-class-in-c/
    getline(std::cin,s);
    for (i = s.begin(); i!= s.end() ; ++i)
    {
        if(*i != ' ')//Encounter a space, output result and
        {            //go to next roman numeral
            int s1 = value(*i);
            if (*(i+1) != ' ' || *(i+1) != '\0') 
            { 
                // Getting value of i+1 nth Element
                int s2 = value(*(i+1)); 

                // Comparing both values 
                if (s1 >= s2) 
                { 
                    // Value of current symbol is greater 
                    // or equal to the next symbol 
                    out = out + s1; 
                } 
                else
                { 
                    out = out + s2 - s1; 
                    i++; // Value of current symbol is 
                         // less than the next symbol 
                } 
            } 
            else
            { 
                out = out + s1; 
                i++; 
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<out<<" ";
            out = 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<out<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
I II MM MCMIV
```

Output:

```
1 2 2000 1904
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the loop? I'm looking to get 9 roman numbers to loop for an output. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible you could edit your answer so I could see in context with the code I provided please?

Comment: @ShrinidhiBhagavath Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, if you have answered a question, and want to add something to it, please use Edit button in the future and add to your answer. Comments can get deleted and that might lead to the loss of valuable information added, use comments only for information that is not entirely necessary in the long run, like clarifications or queries.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any problem doing it like this?

```
cout << "Enter a Roman Numeral" << endl;

string inpval;
cin >> inpval;

while (inpval != "exit")
{
int outval = 0;

if (inpval == "I")
outval = 1;
else if (inpval == "II")
    outval = 2;
else if (inpval == "III")
    outval = 3;
else if (inpval == "IV")
    outval = 4;
// ect
cout << "The Equivalent Arabic value is: " << outval << endl << endl;

cout << "Enter next numeral: (type exit to exit) " << endl;
cin >> inpval;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try this but with the string comes back with an infinite loop, is there a way to do this with Char instead of string?

Comment: How would I do this until End Of File?